# Android - Open an activity one at a time?

Tags: android

I have several buttons placed on my main activity and I wanted the app to open only one whenever the user presses the button. I'm very new to Android so I was wondering how can I open one activity per click of the button? Here's the code I have currently:

```
public class MainActivity3Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button ViewGradesActivity;
Button ClassScheduleActivity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);

    ViewGradesActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewgrades);
    ViewGradesActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

    ClassScheduleActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.classSched);
    ClassScheduleActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent viewgrades = new Intent(this, ViewGradesActivity.class);
    Intent classsched = new Intent(this, classSchedule.class);

    startActivity(viewgrades);
    startActivity(classsched);
}

}
```

With the code above whenever I touch the button that views the grades, the second activity (class schedule) seems to open too. I mean whenever I press a button, two activities open. What should I do?

Thank you for the help :D

Comment: get id from view passed to `onClick` and based on it(simple `if` or `switch` with ids of buttons) start activity that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also put a condition check in onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.viewgrades:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewGradesActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.classSched:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, classSchedule.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This one's easier to understand since I'm a beginner and all.

Answer (score 1):

Each `setOnClickListener` needs to have its own click listener. That will solve your problem.

`ClassScheduleActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ... );`

etc

(or the solution by @nr4bt above will also work)